# How to open files outside of the django project?

Tags: python, django, path

I am building a django view which return the name of the town given the longitude and lattitude passed in an HTTP request. To performs these computations, I wrote a function that needs to open a Geojson file located outside the django project. This function in the same file as the view  :

```
/home/erwan/Images/eosya_app/backend/api/municipality/compute_municipality_view.py
```

In this function, I perform the following open but django does not find the file.

```
  with open('../../../database/unparsed_data/administrative_boundaries/my_file.geojson','r') as f:
```

I made some research and learn that I have to define a base directory path in the settings to be able to access external files. I added the following line to my setting.py :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FILES_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../database/unparsed_data'))
```

I updated the file path accordingly in my function  :

```
file_path = os.path.join(settings.FILES_DIR, '/administrative_boundaries/france-geojson-master/departements.geojson')
```

But django is still unable to find the file. Additionnaly the print does not match the expected path. It look like the FILE_DIR is not taken into account. Here is the result of the print :

```
/administrative_boundaries/france-geojson-master/departements.geojson
```

I also tried to verify my project root path, without success :

```
print(settings.SITE_ROOT)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'SITE_ROOT'
```

What am I doing wrong and how to access my geojson file in this function ?

Answer (score 1):

In `/home/erwan/Images/eosya_app/backend/api/municipality/compute_municipality_view.py`:

```
CURDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
FILES_DIR = os.path.join(CURDIR, '../../../database/unparsed_data/administrative_boundaries/')

...
with open(os.path.join(FILES_DIR, 'france-geojson-master/departements.geojson')) as fp:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py, you should have this line to define the BASE_DIR:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Let's assume your Django project structure is like this:

```
/home/erwan/Images/eosya_app/
  ├── backend/
  │   ├── api/
  │   │   └── municipality/
  │   │       ├── compute_municipality_view.py
  │   │       └── ... (other files and folders)
  │   └── ... (other files and folders)
  ├── database/
  │   └── unparsed_data/
  │       └── administrative_boundaries/
  │           └── my_file.geojson
  └── eosya_app/
      ├── settings.py
      └── ... (other files and folders)
```

In the compute_municipality_view.py, you can access the Geojson file like this:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'database/unparsed_data/administrative_boundaries/my_file.geojson')

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    # Your file processing code here
```

By using settings.BASE_DIR, you are getting the base directory path of your Django project, and then you can construct the path to your Geojson file relative to that base directory.